# Code for chi-square in R as data space is low

Tags: r, feature-selection

```
weights<-chi.squared(Class~.,traindata[1:1000])
```

using this i am getting attributes printed for 999 but once again using. i have to gather data partly as my memory is low

```
weights<-chi.squared(Class~.,traindata[1000:2000])
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Class' not found
```

Comment: please help its very much urgent

Comment: anybody is welcome herre to help wih your experiences.. it is urgent

Answer (score 0):

The column 'Class' is not presented in your data frame. You should put the column name of the class column into the formula